# Book about RPG players who get pulled into their game

Tags: story-identification, books, rpg

I read a book as a teenager and I am searching for it. (from around the 90's)

Things I remember:

- I remember that one of the players was in a wheelchair and he played a dwarf,
- Also remember when the wizard woke up in the game world, he set off a lightning bolt and exploded most of their gear.

I wish I could give you more, I read it and it inspired me to start playing D&D. Want to revisit it.

Comment: Now I'm suspicious *Final Fantasy Tactics Advance* may have been influenced by this story...

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92182/characters-taken-back-in-time-and-into-other-bodies-made-revolvers-to-help-he (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 21):

This is [Guardians of the Flame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Flame) by Rosenberg.  I loved this as a teen as well.

From the book:

> **James Michael Finnegan/Ahira Bandylegs** -- computer sciences major/dwarf warrior

....

> And when you've spent your whole life with muscular dystrophy, you're really lucky, in a way. There's lots more things to dream about. Like being able to punch a computer keyboard at better than a scorching ten words per minute. Like sleeping in a top bunk. Like feeding yourself quickly, wolfing down food so you could run off somewhere. Like using a goddam bathroom without having someone else wipe you off.
>
> Like not having to be so goddam cheerful all the time since because you're a feeb in a chair, people will let you get away with anything as long as you don't touch them.

As regard their arrival and the wizard accidentally blasting things:

> The volley of sound flowed into Aristobulus, his breathing becoming deeper, a tinge of pink replacing the fishbelly pallor of his face. The fingers of an outflung arm twitched, then curled, as his eyes snapped open.
> Aristobulus sucked in air with a desperate gasp, and a stream of sound issued from his mouth, obscenely guttural and harsh.
> And like a striking snake, a bolt of lightning crackled from the tips of his fingers, shattering the nearest of the boxes into a thousand charred, smoking pieces.