# Characters taken back in time and into other bodies. Made revolvers to help. "Heroes" in title?

Tags: story-identification, books

I read the first book in the 90s.  The characters are taken back in time and into other bodies.  There is a man, woman and a dwarf at least.  They use their modern knowledge to help rule.  They make revolvers at the end and the main leader is killed.

Comment: thank you all!!! I'm going to read the series now.  Feels like reuniting with a childhood friend.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After checking with the almighty wiki, I'm pretty sure you read part of the [Guardians of the Flame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Flame) series by Joel Rosenberg..

It's about a group of students playing a fantasy RPG that get transported into the game setting - and into their characters (one a dwarf) - by their gamemaster, who knew it was real and was looking for a way there himself.  They end up staying put and starting a revolt against slavery, founding their own haven nation, and starting some modern tech (including gunpowder and eventually revolvers). Past the first book the fact that it was a game on Earth doesn't get mentioned much.

Per the wiki, one of the novel collections was titled Guardians of the Flame: The Heroes, and contained books 4 and 5 from the series. This is probably what you read.