# Story about group of students trapped in fantasy world by their GM

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find book series, which I read few years ago. As title states, it's about group of students playing board RPG and being trapped inside by their GM. Few points I recall:

- The setting was typical medival fantasy with magic
- GM was their teacher
- One of players was on a wheelchair
- At the end they had own village.

EDIT

I've read these books no more than 10 years ago, and I think they were not new then. I know that doesn't say much, but that's all I can say. Some more details about history itself:

- One of players played as dwarf (I think it was the disabled one) and didn't     really want to come back from there
- They managed to come back to real world at least once
- At least one of them died and has been ressurected

It turns out that this series was found [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28017/book-about-rpg-players-who-get-pulled-into-their-game?rq=1). I've browsed related questions but didn't see it. Sorry for duplicate nonetheless.

Comment: You've started us off with some good details, but you could add some more, such as how long was a few years ago, did you read this in the 2010s? Or the 00s? Was it published around when you read it or long before? You can find some good questions to ask yourself in [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872). I suggest you take a look at it even if you think you couldn't possibly remember anything else, it's pretty good.

Comment: Voting to leave open because the other question doesn't have an accepted answer. You can add a self-answer to this question with what book it is, though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the series I was looking for: [Guardians of the Flame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Flame) by Joel Rosenberg.

Comment: Similar to the guy I showed you before, here's a good [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9445/68872) by the same guy on answering story-id questions. Really adding in details into the answer makes for a much stronger answer, you'll get more attention and you're more likely to help more people. Look at the answer you linked to for inspiration if you need to!